# Extra column in HTML table

Tags: php

May I know how come there is one extra column at my table between the payment id and update payment column which I could not debug? My code is below. 
Note: I could not post the picture as I do not have enough reputation.

```
  <td width="52">Bookng id</td>     
    <td width="78">Deposit</td>
    <td width="149">Total_amt_paid</td>
    <td width="149">Balance</td>
    <td width="149">Payment status</td>
    <td width="57">Card type</td>
     <td width="62">Total price</td>
     <td width="94">Payment id</td>
     <td width="62"></td>
    <td width="293">Update Payment</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <th height="45"><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Booking_id']; ?></th>

    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Deposit']; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Total_amt_paid']; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Balance']; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_status']; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Card_type']; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Total_price']; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_id']; ?></th>
   <th><?php if($row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_status'] == 'Fully Paid'){
               echo "<th><span style='color:grey' href='UpdatePayment.php?Payment_id=".$row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_id']."'> Update</span></th>"; }
              if($row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_status'] == 'Partial'){ 
              echo "<th><a href='UpdatePayment.php?Payment_id=".$row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_id']."'> Update</a></th>";
              }
               ?>
             </th>
```

Comment: You have an extra column in your first tr (<td width="62"></td>). Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Hi if I did not put that extra column, the "update payment" text column  will goes into the blank column  and my "update" link columns will goes into second column leaving the title blank. it will become 2 separated column instead of under one column

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your code:

First, you should get rid of your empty  in the first row

```
<tr>
    <td width="52">Bookng id</td>     
    <td width="78">Deposit</td>
    <td width="149">Total_amt_paid</td>
    <td width="149">Balance</td>
    <td width="149">Payment status</td>
    <td width="57">Card type</td>
    <td width="62">Total price</td>
    <td width="94">Payment id</td>
    <td width="293">Update Payment</td>
</tr>
```

Second, you are opening a `<th>` tag and checking a condition inside and opening a new `<th>` tag inside the condition, so your code should be something like:

```
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Deposit']; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Total_amt_paid']; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Balance']; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_status']; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Card_type']; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Total_price']; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_id']; ?></th>
<?php if($row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_status'] == 'Fully Paid') {
  echo "<th><span style='color:grey' href='UpdatePayment.php?Payment_id=".$row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_id']."'> Update</span></th>";
} else {
echo "<th><a href='UpdatePayment.php?Payment_id=".$row_RecordsetUpdatePayment['Payment_id']."'> Update</a></th>";
} ?>
```

That should be it.

Comment: Excellent. Please, consider mark this answer as the correct one if this is the one that really helped you to fix your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Beside each answer there is a 'tick'. You have to mark the correct answer. Only one can be selected as correct.

Comment: @EngTatChew: see above for how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `<td>` from your header row

```
<tr>
    <td width="52">Bookng id</td>     
    <td width="78">Deposit</td>
    <td width="149">Total_amt_paid</td>
    <td width="149">Balance</td>
    <td width="149">Payment status</td>
    <td width="57">Card type</td>
    <td width="62">Total price</td>
    <td width="94">Payment id</td>
    <td width="293">Update Payment</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi if I did not put that extra column, the "update payment" text column will goes into the blank column and my "update" link columns will goes into second column leaving the title blank. it will become 2 separated column instead of under one column

Comment: are you trying to have two columns so you can scan one column for full and another column for partial? Or are you trying to have one column that could be full or partial?